# How to centered small content of gallery in the middle for android

Tags: android, android-widget

G'day!

I need to centered content (gallery items) by the middle if they have width less than gallery's width.

How can I do that?

Comment: Have you looked for a `gravity` related attribute?

Comment: Okay, what attribute should I use in my case? I had tried to fill_horizontal, but it didn't help.

Comment: ...well you want to `center` the content, right?

Comment: All content of gallery if that is less then width of gallery.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I am understanding your question correctly

Something like this might work:

```
gallery.setSelection((int)(gallery.getCount() /2));
```

If you call that in your onCreate or somewhere it should shift your gallery as close to the middle as it can given how many children it has.

Comment: Okay, I have 4 items =) Current item area is located by the middle of the gallery widget. In that case your answer ain't fine =(

Comment: it is as close as you can get with a gallery I think. There is always an item in the center, which means if your child count is even you'll be off centered. But its closer than all the way off to one side =). You might also try gal.scrollTo(x,y); or gal.scrollBy(x,y); Maybe if you pass in the combined width of all the children divided by 2 it would scoot you over but not leave an item in the middle. I doubt it though.

Comment: Hey! =) gal.scroll(By|To) is exactly what I need! Thx mate!